# Identify an IC Found in a Garage Door Opener

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification, remote-control

Inside a defunct garage door opener I found this IC:

[image: 33192C]

I tried searching for *33192C* with variations of 'datasheet' and such keywords, but I got routed to the usual datasheet farms who are happy to let me know that they don't have it, and oh, by the way, here's an ad!

Can anyone identify this part, and even better, link to a datasheet?

Comment: The *M* emblem is for [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com).  Do you have an idea when the garage door opener was made?

Comment: I can't pin it down, but I know the remote was in active use within the last 15 years.

Comment: The date code suggests 2003, week 38.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through the Microchip KeeLoq "code hopping encoder designed for secure Remote Keyless Entry (RKE) systems" datasheets, I'm 99% sure that this is one of them, either rebranded for a customer, or a close custom version.

[image]

Look for the HCS3xx series. The Packaging Information for those chips show the top code use. 33192c would be the end user custom code.

Comment: Cool! I found datasheets online for the HSC301 and the HSC360. In a couple of weeks we'll put the circuit back on the oscilloscope and try to narrow it down!

Comment: @DonWakefield considering it might be a custom part (instead of just customer numbered), it might not act exactly same as you would expect from one of the datasheet standard parts. I still would assume the general idea/operation is there though.

Answer (score 5):

That is a microchip logo.  They bought a Israeli rolling code generator company for garage openers in the mid -90's.  So that might help you.  Called KeeLoq (I think)

Comment: Yeah, rolling codes sounds familiar. When we had the board up on the oscilloscope, the pulse patterns changed every button press...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I think the 001 3B2 is the HEXadecimal code the chip puts out. The receiver must be programmed to accept it. My remote has 001 386 and the neighbors is 001 00F. All HEX numbers.

Comment: Most modern garage door openers work on a rolling-code system, and the _transmitter_ is used to program the _receiver_, not vice versa.

Comment: Mine is marked:
33192C
001 8JB
M 0126
I think the first line is marked to represent a custom code, but the second line isn’t HEX, with a ‘J’. It would have to be nonadecimal in that case, I guess. ;)
The last line has the M logo and the YYWW date code.